# How to block C++ NCurses from showing pressed key?

Tags: c++, key, ncurses

I am currently creating a Tic-Tac-Toe game in C++. In a fuction to place a tile I am utilizing an endless while cycle that checks getch() and then moves the cursor or places the tile. However when I press something other then enter or arrows it writes that char on the board. But I dont want that. Could you please tell me how to do it ?

```
bool moveCursor ( void )
{
    int c;
    int tmpX = m_Xpos;
    int tmpY = m_Ypos;

    while (1){
        c = getch();

        if(c == KEY_LEFT) tmpX--;
        if(c == KEY_RIGHT) tmpX++;
        if(c == KEY_UP) tmpY--;
        if(c == KEY_DOWN) tmpY++;

        if (tmpY > m_len ) tmpY--;
        if (tmpX > m_len ) tmpX--;
        if (tmpY < 1 ) tmpY++;
        if (tmpX < 1 ) tmpX++;

        if(c == 'q') return false;
        if(c == '\n')
        {
            m_Ypos = tmpY;
            m_Xpos = tmpX;
            if (checkValidMove(tmpY,tmpX))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if ( c != KEY_LEFT && c != KEY_RIGHT && c != KEY_UP && c != KEY_DOWN && c != 'q' && c != '\n' ) continue;//my try to fix it, but didn't work
        move(tmpY,tmpX);
        refresh();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

so yes, I am kind of stupid - I just had to use the noecho() option